# Creating button not calling any action inside form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any way to create a button inside html form that wouldn't call an action specified in "Html.BeginForm"? I want to use it only for adding some elements to form by javascript. I have a different button that should call an action.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm...
{
    ...
    <button id="addRow" class="btn margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10">addRowt</button>
    ...
}
```

The "addRow" button I'd like not to call any action.

Comment: Just add `type="button"` (the default in most browsers will be `type="submit")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can listen to the `click` event of this button and prevent the default behavior. Assuming you ave jQuery library loaded in this page, you may use jquery [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method to do this.

```
$(function(){

  $("#addRow").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     // do other things as needed (ex : add a row to ui)
  }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor tag that looks like a button if you are using `bootstrap` Then you put your JavaScript inside the tag like below:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="YourMethod()" >New Button</a>
```